# Pin confirmation on pic for sd card connector?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, schematics, sd

I've had a first version of a connection to a sd card connector (**DM3CS-SF**) for my **PIC32MX470F512L** that did the following connections:

[image]

After trying to run an harmony example, using this config, the sd card didn't work.

I did then, some digging on the datasheet, i found that the SDI and SDO couldnt be used with that pins.

Input pin selection:
[image]
Output pin selection
[image]

With this i wired this way:

SDO -> RPD3

SDI -> RPF5

[image]
[image]

Am i right? I want to check before making a new PCB.

Comment: Use an eval board or modify your existing board with rework wires to test it first.  If you can't do that, make your new board support multiple options with resistor jumpers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks thats an ideia. I don't have much space available for other connections, if not i think that would be a great solution in my case, i don't have an eval board here and my wire connection for sd card is broken (because of the much tests i did)

Comment: Then your first step should be to get an eval board and/or fix the broken wiring...

Comment: Yes, but according to datasheet this connection seems to be right, that is what i'm asking? Or it is not that linear?

Comment: You'll likely regret committing to a single path that you have not tested - you are already paying for having made that mistake (lack of testing before committing to a path, not the design oversight of picking the wrong pins) once, don't make it again.